# Dynamic delete in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-delete

I have Some static data for that i am creating select statement with the help of union all and i am comparing those data with DB table (departments).. with the help of minus i will get extra records which are in DB table and i need to delete those record......Need to sync up existing records with static data i hope this will clear the requirement..

Trying to delete a resultSet of select query in below query i am not sure where is my mistake.. getting SQL Error: ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view
01732. 00000 -  "data manipulation operation not legal on this view"

Here i am trying to delete all the records from departments which are not matched with 66,77

```
  delete from (select department_id, department_name, manager_id,location_id from departments
     minus
      (select 66,'Administration',200,1700 from dual
    union all
    select 77,'Marketing',201,1800 from dual));
```

Comment: is it not as simple as `delete from departments where department_id not in (66,77)`?

Comment: @vkp thanks for the response i need to do with multiple operation with union all and minus

Comment: I need to compare with all the column values..

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Are you trying to delete from the table or from a result set of a previous query?  If the latter, rewrite the query to return only the rows you want?

Comment: @Dan sorry for your confusion I am comparing both the query result.. This will give you the comparison result select department_id, department_name, manager_id,location_id from departments
     minus
      (select 66,'Administration',200,1700 from dual
    union all
    select 77,'Marketing',201,1800 from dual    and i want to delete that

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are trying to do, and in plain English. The requirement is not clear. "I am comparing" (in your last comment) is not a requirement. A requirement is something like this: I have a table (name) with these columns, and here are a few representative rows. (And do include a few representative rows.) I must delete rows from this table. (If in fact that is the assignment). Namely, I must delete the rows that satisfy the following conditions: (and state those conditions). Don't worry about MINUS and UNION - perhaps those are part of the solution, but not the REQUIREMENT

Comment: @MathGuy i have Some static data for that i am creating select statement with the help of union all so i am comparing those data with DB table (departments).. with the help of minus i will get extra records which are in DB table and i need to delete those record......Need to sync up existing records with static data i hope this will clear the requirement.. sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  delete departments

  where  department_id in
         (
            select department_id

            from  (    select  department_id, department_name, manager_id,location_id 
                       from    departments

                       minus

                       (          select 66,'Administration',200,1700 from dual
                       union all  select 77,'Marketing'     ,201,1800 from dual
                       )
                   )
         )
```

or

```
  delete departments

  where  (department_id, department_name, manager_id,location_id) not in
         (          select 66,'Administration',200,1700 from dual
         union all  select 77,'Marketing'     ,201,1800 from dual
         )
```

But make sure you don't have `select null,null,null,null from dual` among your UNION ALL records or nothing will be deleted

Comment: This was based on the original  try, added a cleaner answer

Comment: Ok thanks for clear one .. but in my case that won't be the case for null.. :)

Answer (score 1):

`delete`s work on tables, not results of select statements. Here, you just want to delete all the records besides those with IDs 66 and 77:

```
DELETE FROM departments WHERE id NOT IN (66, 77)
```

Comment: you mean to say where ( select * from tab)  wont work...correct me if m wrong

Comment: @vinod yup. It may work on some edge case queries, but as a general rule of thumb, it doesn't.

Comment: i was referring this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548751/how-to-write-a-sql-delete-statement-with-a-select-statement-in-the-where-clause thanks for your response

Comment: @vinod oh, my bad, having a query in the **where** clause is something completely different than what you tried to do in the OP.

Comment: okay so its confirmed we can not delete the resultset I will go with NOT IN approach

Comment: @mathguy i have added my comment kindly check